# Google maps API not displaying on Apple Products

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps-api-3

I have been dealing with this challenge for a day now and nothing I have found has worked. Here is my situation .

- Google Maps with drawing manager is not loading on Apple Products (works perfectly fine on android and PC.). More specificially, it works as intended on Google Chrome on a Mac, but not for chrome/firefox/safari on the iphone/ipad.

Error log :

```
setMap:not an instance of Map. 
undefined is not an object (evaluating map.data.addGeoJson)
```

Problem areas :

setMap :

```
function enable_draw() {
    if (!drawingManager) {
        drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.polygon,
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
                drawingModes: ['polygon']
            }
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
    }
```

object is undefined:

```
  var inJSON = JSON.parse(propertyCfc.getpropJSON(parseInt($('#propID').val())).DATA.BUILDINGPOLY[0]);
    map.data.addGeoJson(inJSON);
```

Map is the div and a global variable.

Declaration of js scripts in cfm :

```
  <script sync type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script sync src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAl8lwM6B2AZsYwoOU1QLCz3Eqgbsub1oM&libraries=drawing,geometry"></script>
  <script sync src="path/globalvars.js"></script>
  <script sync type="text/javascript" src="path/main_map.js"></script>
  <script sync type="text/javascript" src="path/posting_geoJSON.js"></script>
  <script sync type="text/javascript" src="path/making_geoJSON.js"></script>
  <script sync type="text/javascript" src="path/drawing.js"></script>
```

What I have tried:
- Set the map within the drawing manager. No effect.

- Setting the Google mapsAPI to be async. Error of :google not defined
- Replacing the callback in the cfm to the following :

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initMap);
> });
> ```

Comment: Can you check if this is happening in all versions of Maps JavaScript API? I can see that currently you are loading the experimental version (there is no v=3 parameter). Can you add v=3 and confirm that release version is also affected? Have a look at versioning model [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions).

Comment: Confirmed on version 3 as well as 3.27 on my end

Comment: I am having this problem / did you get to the bottom of it?